# ui-router resolve is not working with the index page controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to resolve some value before I load the first page of my application, but it kept telling me

Unknown provider: programClassSummaryProvider <- programClassSummary <- HomeCtrl

I pretty sure I did it correctly, because I did the same thing for any other controller and routing. but it is not working for my homepage controller. 
It seems like it load the controller first, before it is resolved in the routing. Anything wrong with my code?

In routing.js

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          templateUrl: 'index_main.html',
          resolve: {
            programClassSummary: ['GroupDataFactory', function (groupDf) {
              return groupDf.getProgramClassSummary();
            }]
          },
          ncyBreadcrumb: {
            skip: true
          }
        });
```

in controller.js

```
angular
    .module('issMccApp')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', homeCtrl);

  homeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$auth', 'programClassSummary'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function homeCtrl($scope, $location, $state, $auth, programClassSummary) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    vm.programClassSummary = programClassSummary;

    if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      $state.go('login');
      return;
    }

    function isAuthenticated() {
      return $auth.isAuthenticated();
    }
  }
```

in factory.js

```
 function getProgramClassSummary(showAll) {
      var query = "";
      if (showAll)
        query = APIConfigObj.base_url + '/api/group/infor/programclasssummary?all=1';
      else
        query = APIConfigObj.base_url + '/api/group/infor/programclasssummary';

      return $http.get(query)
        .success(function (result) {
          return result;
        })
        .error(function (err) {
          return err;
        })

    }
```

Comment: If the controller is being loaded before the resolve happens, you might be loading the controller twice (for example by using `ng-controller` in the HTML).

Comment: You are absolutely correct !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, we really have to distinguish the `UI-Router` state world, and angular itself. Reason why is clearly defined here *(extracted [$resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$resolve) from [UI-Router API documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router))*:

#### [$resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$resolve)

> `resolve(invocables, locals, parent, self)`
>
> Resolves a set of invocables. An invocable is a function to be invoked via `$injector.invoke()`, and can have an arbitrary number of dependencies. An invocable can either return a value directly, or a `$q` promise. If a promise is returned it will be resolved and the resulting value will be used instead. Dependencies of invocables are resolved (in this order of precedence)
>
> - from the specified locals
> - from another invocable that is part of this $resolve call
> - from an invocable that is inherited from a parent call to $resolve (or recursively
> - from any ancestor $resolve of that parent).

There is [a wroking plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zB1Bb6DCWz6TDwPXbiXJ?p=preview), which uses this *index.html*

```
<body ng-controller="RootCtrl">

    a summary for a root:
    <pre>{{summary}}</pre>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home">home</a>
      <li><a href="#/other">other</a>
    </ul>

    <div ui-view=""></div>
```

So, here we use some `RootCtrl`, which won't go through state machine UI-Router, it is angular basic stuff

The root controller must be defined as

```
.controller('RootCtrl', ['$scope', 'GroupDataFactory', function ($scope, groupDf) { 
  $scope.summary = groupDf.getProgramClassSummary();
}])
```

For a state home, we can use different approach, in fact the same as above (simplifed version below)

```
  .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
      resolve: {
          programClassSummary: ['GroupDataFactory', function (groupDf) {
          return groupDf.getProgramClassSummary();
        }]
      },
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
  })
```

And its controller is now able to consume the **locals**

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'programClassSummary', function ($scope, summary) { 
  $scope.summaryForHome = summary;
}])
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zB1Bb6DCWz6TDwPXbiXJ?p=preview)